# Is this shorter phrase awkward?

Tags: legalese

In legalese, while describing a party which loses the capacity to perform certain obligation, is it awkward to say "During the course of the calamity, the performance incapacitated (or disabled) party shall ..." instead of "During the course of the calamity, the party who is incapacitated by the said event to perform the obligation, shall…"? I would be happy to know if there are better ways to convey the meaning succinctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Legalese often uses defined terms to make an initially long term more succinct. The definition is offered the first time the concept is used and is usually thereafter capitalized.

> During the course of the calamity, the party who is incapacitated by the said event to perform the obligation (the "Incapacitated Party"), shall ...

When *Incapacitated Party* next appears, the reader would understand it to mean the entire phrase.

The use of *incapacitated* or *disabled* without further explanation that it is a result of a particular calamity that is the subject of the legal document might be misread to mean a person who was incapacitated or disabled because of some other, unrelated event.

Comment: I have already defined "performance" and "performing" elsewhere as performing a certain contracted obligation. Would "performance incapacitated (disabled) party" already excluded the case of incapacitation by some other unrelated event?

Comment: No. What if a person were physically incapacitated by illness rather than the calamity? They might be unable to perform according to definition, but not be covered by this provision.